# How to initialize map with elements in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I woule like to create this map and add few elements to it while initialization. The key should be the name of the person.
How this can be achieved?

```
 let person1: Person = ...
 let person2: Person = ...
 let map: { [key: string]: Person } = {
        person1.name = person1,
        person2.name = person2
      };
```

but this doesn't compile. How to put some elements inside?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can go with:

```
let map: { [key: string]: Person } = {
    [person1.name]: person1,
    [person2.name]: person2
};
```